# Is there a way to use a list to make the columns of a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I want to ultimately create a dataframe that has a large number of columns and rows. To make the code easier to read, however, I would like to store the column names in a separate file and ultimately create a blank dataframe with the specified columns.

For example, I would want the following stored in a `constants.R` file:

```
column_list <- c("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "C10")
```

I would then want to use this `column_list` to make a `data.frame` object with the 10 conditions as columns. For examples sake, how could I use this list to make a dataframe with 10 columns (as specified above) and 50 rows?

I would want the 500 values (10 columns x 50 rows) to be populated with NA as of right now. They will be filled in later.

Answer (score 2):

You can create data with required dimension and column names using `matrix` function and convert it to dataframe.

```
column_list <- c("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "C10")
nr <- 50
nc <- 10
data <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = nr,ncol = nc,dimnames = list(NULL,column_list)))
data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data.frame` and creating the `NA`'s with `rep` and setting the `colnames` with `setNames`:

```
column_list <- c("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "C10")
nrows <- 50
DF <- data.frame(
  setNames(
    rep(list(rep(NA, nrows)), length(column_list))
  , column_list
  )
)
```

Performance:

```
column_list <- c("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "C10")
nrows <- 1e5
bench::mark(ronakShah = data.frame(matrix(nrow = nrows,ncol = length(column_list),
    dimnames = list(NULL,column_list))) #Changed to use length(column_list)
, Gki = data.frame(setNames(rep(list(rep(NA, nrows)),
    length(column_list)), column_list))
)
#  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1 ronakShah    3.04ms   3.14ms      269.    11.4MB    188.     63    44
#2 Gki        767.45µs 801.35µs     1240.   390.7KB     18.8   592     9
```

Currently using `rep` in `data.frame` is *faster* and using *less memory* than creating an intermediate `matrix`.